# Execution reverted error mesage

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

I am using transaction builder app on gnosis safe wallet to recover an nft I send to the wrong chain by accident. I created a new wallet on the correct chain with the address I sent to nft to, and am using this in the transaction builder app.

I have used 'safetransferfrom' & 'transferfrom' in contract method selector but it wont let me even send the transaction. When i simulate the transaction i get 'execution reverted' error message.

Here is the tenderly link showing the info: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/public/safe/safe-apps/simulator/c589c227-edf4-4936-99dc-d290d0af3a40?trace=0.0.6